# html help frameset

Tags: html, scroll, frame

I'm working on my html project, and everything is going well.

Now I'm doing the same project with framesets, but I discovered that the page in a frame set won't scroll as a whole page (you can only scroll each frame at a time).

How can i solve this?

Please help

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is perhaps a static design around your scrolling content, correct?

If so, what you should actually do is make a single page (not a frameset) with your desired DIV layout ([a good example can be found here](http://www.webreference.com/authoring/style/sheets/layout/advanced/)), and then have your content div use CSS that will allow it to scroll (e.g. `overflow:scroll;`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Voted up! Primarily because I prefer your answer to mine - I was being lazy. ^_^

Comment: Voted your comment up because that's awesome. ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use frames!** I know this is a horrible answer to your question, but believe me - loads of peeps would agree!

If you can, use plain ol' CSS and NO FRAMES.

Also, there is *rogue* synchronised scrolling Javascripts floating around on the Interwebs - But I wouldn't use them. People who have Javascript off won't get that effect.